# Looking for a pythonic way to handle tree of directory paths

Tags: python

I am writing a few snippets to handle directory paths for asset management. Basically I will supply some arguments and I would like to get back paths that fall into a specific convention.

For example, I will pass values for `proj_name`, `asset_type`, `asset_name`, `version`, ect.

```
asset_type1:
/projects/proj_name/assets/asset_type1/asset_name/version/filename.ext

asset_type2:
/projects/proj_name/assets/asset_type2/asset_name/version/sub_version/filename.ext

asset_type3:
/projects/proj_name/assets/asset_type3/asset_name/version/proxy/filename.ext

asset_type4:
/projects/proj_name/seq_assets/asset_type4/asset_name/version/filename.ext
```

There are variations on the path tree depending on the asset type I am dealing with.
The code must be flexible so I can easily adapt new assets with potential variations on sub path conventions.
If I pass incomplete arguments, I should have the option to get back a default path (eg if I dont supply version, or filename)

I am looking for a pythonic way to handle this... so far my approaches have just turned into ugly if trees which I know will be a pain to adapt in the future.

This is essentially where I am at with the example above. My biggest issue is that the path convention is not clear. In my actually production code, there are a lot more potential branches.

```
def getPath(proj_name='proj_name', asset_type='asset_type1', asset_name=None, version=None, sub_version=None, proxy=False, filename=None):

        # handle default values
        # ...

        path_args = []
        path_args.append('/projects')

        if asset_type == 'asset_type4':
            path_args.append('seq_assets')

        else:
            path_args.append('assets')

        path_args.append(asset_type)
        path_args.append(asset_name)
        path_args.append(version)

        if sub_version:
            path_args.append(sub_version)

        if proxy:
            path_args.append(proxy)

        path_args.append(filename)

        return os.path.join(*path_args)
```

Comment: Nice question, but you should provide your work for use to see what you've tried.

Comment: You can use os.walk module. Do provide your work.

Comment: I've updated the question with an example of where I'm headed so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a dictionary of format strings.

```
asset_paths = {
    'type1': "/projects/{project}/assets/{type}/{name}/{version}/{filename}.{ext}",
    'type2': "/projects/{project}/assets/{type}/{name}/{version}/{filename}.{ext}",
    'type3': "/projects/{project}/assets/{type}/{name}/{version}/{filename}.{ext}",
    'type4': "/projects/{project}/seq_assets/{type}/{name}/{version}/{filename}.{ext}"
}

def asset_path(project, type,
               name='name', version='1.0', filename='filename', ext='ext',
               **kwargs):

    # Branching arguments
    if 'sub_version' in kwargs  &&  kwargs['sub_version']:
        version = version + '/' + kwargs['sub_version']
    if 'proxy' in kwargs  &&  kwargs['proxy']:
        filename = kwargs['proxy'] + '/' + filename

    return asset_paths[type].format(project=project, type=type, name=name,
                                    version=version, filename=filename, ext=ext,
                                    **kwargs)

asset_path('prj', 'type1', 'fred', version='2.1')
# returns '/projects/prj/assets/type1/fred/2.1/filename.ext'

asset_path('prj', 'type2', 'fred', sub_version='b')
# returns '/projects/prj/assets/type2/fred/1.0/b/filename.ext'
```

Here, `project` and `type` are two required arguments, `name`, `version`, `filename` and `ext` are arguments with default values, and you can provide as many extra keyword arguments as needed for the format string of the given type.

- `sub_version`, if present and non-empty, will be appended to `version`.
- `proxy`, if present and non-empty, will be prepended to `filename`.

Comment: I like where this is going, but in my case I would have more potential branches, For example 'type2' may also have a proxy dir before filename, and type may determine if the path is in an assets path or an seq_assets path.

Comment: Ok, I thought it was obvious, but it was copy-n-paste to add it into the answer.  Now, both 'type3' has the proxy dir in it, and 'type4' uses the seq_assets path, instead of the assets path.  Or am I not understanding?

Comment: Here's a potential convention: {version}/{sub_version}/{proxy}/{filename} 
But proxy is optional, if I dont pass proxy I will end up with an incomplete path.

Comment: My example above may be poor. The more general problem I am trying to solve is that the paths can potentially branch in zero or more places, right now your example will cover for one level of branching.

Comment: Yes, I read your problem as `type1` having one format, and `type2` having a different format (with a `sub_version` field).  If these fields are truly optional, and may appear in any type, then you have to do some argument processing (shown in edit), or default them to empty strings and replace `//` sequences with a `/` afterwards.